# Unity 4.6 change slider value

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I've been struggling with something in Unity 4.6 that should be simple. I'm trying to set the slider value  All the public objects are defined in the inspector, but I get the error warning

I tried pasting the code, but kept getting errors here saving it saying my code was not properly indented. Anyway, the problem is preserving a horizontal slider setting between game sessions. the line where the error occurs is

slider.value = volume;

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Jerry

Comment: What language are you using? And what is the error?

Comment: Using C#. I have the slider assigned in the inspector. The error is as follows: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
VolumeControl.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/VolumeControl.cs:14)

Comment: @jadkins4 If Stack Overflow isn't letting you post your code, can you paste your code into a pastebin.com or something?

Comment: the NullReference probably means you have something that is supposed to be assigned in the unity editor but is not. Without more code we can't help much, however.

Comment: Trying again to insert code: This time, it took out the formatting altogether.

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class VolumeControl : MonoBehaviour {

 public Text volumeText;
 public Slider slider;
 public AudioSource audioSource;
 private float volume;

 void Start(){
  volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("volume");
  slider.value = volume;
 }

 public void ChangeVolume(float volume){
  audioSource.volume = volume;
  AudioListener.volume = volume;
  PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("volume", volume );
 }
}